# Angular - append values to a json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following json. I want to traverse this and get values for those keys where 'check' value is 'true'.

```
{
  "A_B":{
    "ID":"09|_|06",
    "address":"ABC",
    "name":"2222222222",
    "Documents":{
      "1":{
        "format":"xlsx"
      },
      "2":{
        "format":"pdf"
      }
    },
    "check":true
  },
  "C_B":{
    "ID":"0a|_|0b",
    "address":"Los Angeles",
    "name":"4444444444",
    "Documents":{
      "1":{
        "format":"docx"
      },
      "4":{
        "format":"xlsx"
      }
    },
    "check":true
  },
  "C_E":{

    "ID":"05|_|06",
    "address":"",
    "name":"1111111111",
    "Documents":{
      "5":{
        "format":"xlsx"
      }
    },
    "check":false
  }
}
```

In the example json above, values for A_B and C_B should be added to the new json. The new json would look like

```
{
  "A_B":{
    "ID":"09|_|06",
    "address":"ABC",
    "name":"2222222222",
    "Documents":{
      "1":{
        "format":"xlsx"
      },
      "2":{
        "format":"pdf"
      }
    },
    "check":true
  },
  "C_B":{
    "ID":"0a|_|0b",
    "address":"Los Angeles",
    "name":"4444444444",
    "Documents":{
      "1":{
        "format":"docx"
      },
      "4":{
        "format":"xlsx"
      }
    },
    "check":true
  }
}
```

I am able to get those IDs [A_B and C_B] where 'check' === true, using the below code

```
var IDs = Object.keys(completeJson);
var checkTrueIDs = IDs.reduce(function(initArr,ID) {
        if(completeJson.check === true) {
                initArr.push(ID);
        }
        return initArr;
},[]);
console.log("IDs wth check === true - " + checkTrueIDs);
```

However, I am not able to get complete object for these IDs and add them to a new JSON. If I do

```
var newJson = {}
```

and then inside the if condition (below the push)

```
newJson = completeJson[ID];
```

this overwrites the previous values, so in the end I am left with only one object.

Comment: There isn't _any_ json in this question. Those are just JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the object that you have and if its key  check is true then add it to the  newJson object.

```
var newJson ={};
    angular.forEach(completeJson, function(value, key) {
    if(value.check){
    newJson[key] = value;
    }
   });
console.log(newJson);
```